# are the larger snails in Hawaii edible?

Tags: seafood

We live in Hawaii and their are lots of larger (really big) land snails.  I don't know if I can eat one but I was wondering if it can be eaten.

If it can be eaten, how would it be best to prepare them, or what can I pair them with?

Answer (score 4):

The name of the snail in Hawaii Achatina fulica.  It's is edible but must be prepared properly according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achatina_fulica). Here's a [video on the subject of preparing them](http://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/wordofmouth/2009/jul/03/african-land-snails-video) linked to in the Wiki article.

Comment: Interesting. One of the worlds worst invasive species. Almost always a good reason to eat something! –

Comment: And there's also the warning in wikipedia : "In the wild, this species often harbors the parasitic nematode Angiostrongylus cantonensis, which can cause a very serious meningitis in humans. Human cases of this meningitis usually result from a person having eaten the raw or undercooked snail, but even handling live wild snails of this species can infect a person with the nematode and thus cause a life-threatening infection."

Comment: In my country of origin (Cuba) we are always told not to touch those snails with our bare hands...

Answer (score 0):

Pipipi snails are small black ones found at the ocean shoreline. We ate them whenever we had a party.
The larger land snails were called ‘African snails.’ They invaded the yard and gardens of Hawaii. We poured salt on it to kill them. Never heard of anyone eating it though.